# How to merge sort ordered lists in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, mergesort

So I need to right a program in MIPS assembly language. My instructions are as follows:

> Write a "merge" program that merges two ordered lists of integers into a new ordered list.
>   For example, given two ordered lists (9,6,4,1) and (7,3,2,0) as input arguments, "merge" should produce a new list (9,7,6,4,3,2,1,0) which is also ordered. Another example could be to merge (6,0,-3) and (9,5,4,0,-2) to produce (9,6,5,4,0,0,-2,-3).
>
> The "merge" program assumes that the two input lists (in decreasing order) of integers are stored in the data area. It loads the integers and merges them into an ordered list. The resulting ordered list (e.g. (9,6,5,4,0,0,-2,-3)) should be stored back into the data area.
>
> It is at your own choice how the data area (i.e. the lists) is arranged, and whether the resulting list is overwritten onto the original two lists. But be sure to give meaningful labels and clearly indicate (using label or comments) where the merged list is stored. Before your program terminates, it should print out the merged list which should be in decreasing order.
>
> Note: Please do NOT implement any sorting algorithm! You will receive a grade of zero (0) if you do so.

*I think the instructions are really unclear here. I'm not sure whether I should give the lists or assume these lists already exist. Any examples or advice/programs would help greatly!

Comment: Are these linked lists or arrays? You could write the code in C first, then convert to assembly (some compilers can produce the assembly code for you).

Comment: I don't see why we should do your homework if you didn't at least do some effort to start it and ask *when you encounter a difficulty*

Comment: Hey I am not here for someone to write code for me. I am simply wanting links to similar examples you might know of and more so clarification as to what this professor is asking for. I found his directions confusing and its spring break so I cannot consult the prof directly. The comment above yours highlights this as I am not sure if prof wants linked list or array. I cant write my program without knowing that okay Bregalad

Comment: rcgldr I'm not sure. Do you have any idea? His use of "list" makes me wanna say linked list but honestly Im not sure. thanks for the tip though! I don't know C unfortunetly. Does a similar tool exist for java? Also, in your experience how accurate are these converters? Do they accurately print to console and perform the correct functions once used in a mips simulator like mars?

Comment: The type of the "list" doesn't matter. I propose to take the simplest one: an array. Also, you can assume that the lists already exist in the data area and you don't need to design an input procedure. Concentrate on the merging algorithm without sorting *and* the output algorithm.

Comment: okay so I think my professor wants us to do linked list though as that is what we were going over in class. I figured out the merging algorthim, but how do I print to the console the contents of a linked list in descending order? Can you explain/give example in terms of java? that'll help me understand more @rkhb

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker. I read *"...the merged list which should be in decreasing order."* as *"the merged list has elements in (hopefully) decreasing order"* and you shouldn't print that in reversed order but from the first element to the last element (Java keyword: ListIterator).

Comment: @rkhb  Yes that is what I ended up doing. I got confused with the decreasing thing so I just added the elements to the lists in decreasing order to begin with

Answer (score 0):

As desired, an example in horrible Java:

```cs
import java.util.*;
class merge {

// Data Area

//static LinkedList list1 = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(9,6,4,1));
//static LinkedList list2 = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(7,3,2,0));
static LinkedList list1 = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(6,0,-3));
static LinkedList list2 = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(9,5,4,0,-2));
static LinkedList list3 = new LinkedList();

// Code Area

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ListIterator<Integer> list1Iterator = list1.listIterator();
    ListIterator<Integer> list2Iterator = list2.listIterator();

    Integer i1 = list1Iterator.next();
    Integer i2 = list2Iterator.next();

    while (true)            // endless, breaks when one of the list reaches its end
    {
        if (i1 > i2)
        {
            list3.add(i1);
            if (list1Iterator.hasNext())
            {
                i1 = list1Iterator.next();
            }
            else            // no element left in list1, fill list3 with the rest of list2 and break
            {
                list3.add (i2);
                while (list2Iterator.hasNext())
                {
                    list3.add(list2Iterator.next());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            list3.add(i2);
            if (list2Iterator.hasNext())
            {
                i2 = list2Iterator.next();
            }
            else            // no element left in list2, fill list3 with the rest of list1 and break
            {
                list3.add (i1);
                while (list1Iterator.hasNext())
                {
                    list3.add(list1Iterator.next());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println (list3);
}

} // class merge
```

Comment: thank you! i actually ended up figuring out how to do it myself in mips after reading the textbook some more. But I appreciate your help